# I'm having trouble setting up SSH connection to Github

Tags: ssh-keys

I'm a new student, about to begin a full stack developer boot camp. I've been tasked with setting up my SSH keys. I have my passphrase set up and added the SSH key to github but when I check the terminal with "ssh -T git@github.com" the fingerprint in the message is not an exact match to the  the GitHub’s RSA public key fingerprint. After following the steps in the prework, and reading through the GitHub docs I can't seem to figure out why the numbers aren't matching up. I confirmed authentication and this is what I'm seeing:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.113)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Hi girlnotfound! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I confirmed authentication even thought they don't match completely. The fingerprints start the same with SHA256: the rest of the characters are not an exact match. Is this how it's supposed to be or did I miss a step along the way?

Comment: At first glance that key fingerprint seems to match the one documented here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints specifically the Ed25519 key. If you are looking at some other source, then those might only list one or some of the others, but modern SSH will pick this one.

Comment: What @JoachimSauer said: you're seeing the Ed25519 key, which is not the same as the RSA key. That is the correct fingerprint for the Ed25519 key, though, so you're good here.

Comment: Thank you so much! So does that mean that it was set up correctly and should I add the ssh key entries to my ~/.ssh/known_hosts file to avoid manually verifying GitHub hosts like directed in the link you provided?